# play next song when music when music is finished in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

i was trying to build a music app. music is playing perfectly but when music finished it not playing next song. i was searching for this solution. when i try whit some solution is's give me error.

> erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>   reason: '-[Shironamhin.MusicPlayer playerDidFinishPlaying:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17003d960

i was trying this way

```
class MusicPlayer: NSObject {

    static let player = MusicPlayer()

    //this is global variable
    var player : AVPlayer?
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

    func initPlayer(){
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                print("AVAudioSession is Active")

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
    func playMusic(_ musicUrl: String?) {
        if let mm = musicUrl {
            var url: URL!
            url = URL(string: mm)
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            player?.volume = 1.0
            player?.rate = 1.0
            player?.play()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)


        }

        func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {

            print("call")

        }
    }




}
```

> Also how can i implement this playerDidFinishPlaying??

Comment: You should move `playerDidFinishPlaying` outside of `playMusic`.

Comment: i moved it. but still same error. can you please share the cod??

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 3, you must declare `Selectors` like this: `#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(email:))` and since Swift 4 you must add the `@objc` attribute to the function:

```
@objc func audioDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("call")
}
```

By the way, `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` has a nice function: `optional func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)`, it may be easier to use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @user6603599, that's what i use.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("\naudioPlayerDidFinishPlaying")
}
```

make sure your MusicPlayer class is set up for this like so:

class MusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {